# how do i write a text file to csv in python with consideration to columns

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, numpy, scipy

I want to write this text file to CSV with consideration to the tab separated columns in the text.  I want the columns to be State, Jan, Feb, Mar, etc.  (the numbers are average temperature)

the text file follows the the following format

```
State           Jan    Feb    Mar    Apr    May    Jun    Jul    Aug    Sep    Oct    Nov    Dec Average
Alabama           44.29  48.04  55.47  61.99  69.89  76.75  79.87  79.04  73.88  63.08  54.10  46.85   62.77
Arizona           42.27  46.24  51.03  57.63  66.01  75.51  80.19  78.50  72.52  61.61  49.64  42.51   60.31
Arkansas          38.48  43.76  51.96  60.36  68.62  76.40  80.57  79.26  72.26  61.47  50.32  41.59   60.42
California        45.14  48.51  51.76  56.50  63.11  70.18  75.32  74.62  69.97  61.56  51.17  44.98   59.40
Colorado          23.71  28.34  35.57  43.06  52.50  62.15  67.60  65.75  57.72  46.64  33.51  25.20   45.15
Connecticut       25.96  28.43  36.94  47.07  57.77  66.29  71.52  69.77  61.68  50.60  41.43  31.13   49.05
Delaware          33.95  35.93  44.04  53.02  62.80  71.59  76.45  74.70  68.08  56.95  47.33  38.44   55.27
Florida           58.09  59.99  64.90  69.29  75.36  79.98  81.60  81.44  79.42  72.66  66.01  59.99   70.73
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
with open('path/to/input') as infile, open('path/to/output', 'w') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for row in csv.reader(infile):
        writer.write(row)
```

Comment: The syntax may have changed since this was originally written... now it would be `writer.writerow(row)`